# Can someone help me for a specific set notation pls?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I want to note a subset of a set of documents (Catalog) such as in each document of this subset there is at least one field (a document is an ensemble of fields), such as the result of a similarity function between this field and at least one element (interest) from another set (userInterests) is greater or equal to a threshold AND the pair (field, interest) is not part of the set "negativeFeedbacks" (which is a set of pairs of interest and field).

My best attempt:

$$MySet = \{ document \in Catalog | \exists_{field \in document}\exists_{interest \in userInterests}Similarity(field, interest) \ge threshold \land (field, interest) \notin negativeFeedbacks \}$$

Is this correct? Do you have any advice? Maybe it's too confusing.
Originally I wrote pseudo code to denote that (I'm in computer science), but professors advised me to use mathematic notation instead.

Comment: Maybe [Relational algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra) may help.